No puedo acceder a mi ssh después de instalar Firewalld
Desde que hice un apt install firewalld, no puedo acceder a mi servidor alojado en Oracle como una isntancia. Este se quedó completamente congelado e inaccesible después de que por pantalla se imprimiera un mensaje como Searching proceses. Ahora no puedo acceder a la máquina ni por ssh, ni por ftp, ni por ningún otro lado.

Si instalaste un firewall, es de pensar que este está bloqueando el acceso al puerto. Lee la documentación del producto y configúralo para que el puerto de SSH esté abierto.  Si usas el default, el puerto es el 22.

Como comenta jachguate parece que has cerrado todas las puertas y te dejaste las llaves dentro... No solo lo debes haber instalado,  sino que lo  tienes que haber habilitado vía systemctl, sin configurarlo adecuadamente antes para permitir el trafico del servicio ssh. Por lo general la única solución es un acceso físico al server, o en el caso de VM practicamente todos los proveedores permiten el acceso a una consola de emergencia de la VM si contactas con ellos (o pueden ejecutar lo necesario por ti)

En tu caso bastaria con detener y desahabilitar el proceso (systemctl stop firewalld y  systemctl disable firewalld) y ya tendrias acceso de nuevo, luego habilita los servicios necesarios ssh, ftp, http, etc antes de volver a iniciarlo. Te recomiendo no habilitar el servicio (systemctl enable firewalld) hasta estar totalmente seguro de que todo está correctamente configurado, simplemente inicialo (systemctl start firewalld) pero no lo habilites, si metes la pata un simple reinicio del server/VM te da acceso de nuevo.
